# Ensure that Entity has a non-private constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring and get problem in first controller on "mapper" filed:

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'modelMapperFactoryBean': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.modelmapper.ConfigurationException: ModelMapper configuration errors:
>
> 1. Failed to instantiate proxied instance of
>    Entity. Ensure that
>    Entity has a non-private constructor.

My Entity is not abstract class. Here it is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity", schema = "public")
public class Entity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("agency")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "entity_fk", value = ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT))
    private Agency agency;

    @Column(name = "brand_name", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String brandName;

    @Column(name = "brand_image")
    private String brandImage;

    @Column(name = "billing_contact")
    @Email(message = "This field should be valid email")
    private String billingContact;

    public Entity() {}
```

It seems ok. And my controller that cannot initialize:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_AGENT')")
public class Controller extends BaseController {
    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    logic...
```

I have config for mapping:

```
    @Component
    public class ModelMapperCustomConfigurer extends ModelMapperCustomConfigurerBase {
    
        private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    
        public void configure(ModelMapper modelMapper) {
            super.configure(modelMapper);
            modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
    
            TypeMap<Entity, EntityDTO> entityEntityDTOTypeMap = modelMapper.createTypeMap(Entity.class, EntityDTO.class);
            entityEntityDTOTypeMap.addMapping(Entity::getBrandImage, EntityDTO::setBrandLogo);

..other mapping not of Entity...
```

All what I found it is about abstract entities, but I have not abstract and I'm getting this mistake... Why?

**UPD**

```
public class BaseController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AgentRepository agentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CampaignRepository campaignRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ManagementRepository managementRepository;

    @Autowired
    private JWTVerifier jwtVerifier;

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    private static final String AGENT_GROUP_NAME = "agents";
    private static final String INTERNAL_GROUP_NAME = "internal";

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseController.class);
    
    protected void jwtVerify() {
        String jwtToken = request.getHeader(Jwt.JWT_HEADER_NAME);
        
        if (jwtToken == null) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException(String.format("Header '%s' not found", Jwt.JWT_HEADER_NAME));
        }
        
        String backdoor = request.getHeader("thisisyuri");
        if (backdoor != null && backdoor.equals("1")) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            jwtVerifier.verify(jwtToken);
        } catch (JWTVerificationException e) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the logged in user's token or thorws an exception if no token is found
     *
     * @return
     */
    protected TokenData getTokenData() {
        Object tokenObj = request.getAttribute(JwtInterceptor.TOKEN_HEADER_NAME);
        if (tokenObj == null) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException("No token provided");
        }
        
        // token verify
        jwtVerify();
        
        return (TokenData) tokenObj;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the logged in user or throws exception if it is not found
     *
     * @return
     */
    protected IGenericUser getUserByToken() {
        TokenData token = getTokenData();
        if (isAgent(token)) {
            Agent existingAgent = agentRepository.findByUid(token.sub)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> {
                        String msg = String.format("Agent not found for Uid: %s", token.sub);
                        logger.warn(msg);
                        return new ResourceNotFoundException(msg);
                    });

            /* For internal admin use - pretend to be a different user */
            if (isInternal(token)) {
                /* Check if pretendUID is set/reset */
                final String switchedUid = request.getHeader("pretendUID");
                if (switchedUid != null) {
                    User pretendUser = null;
                    if (switchedUid.equals("0")) {
                        existingAgent.setPretendUid(null);
                    } else {
                        /* Supporting only pretend to be an influencer for now */
                        pretendUser = userRepository.findByUid(switchedUid)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> {
                                    String msg = String.format("Pretend User not found for Uid: %s", switchedUid);
                                    logger.warn(msg);
                                    return new ResourceNotFoundException(msg);
                                });
                        existingAgent.setPretendUid(pretendUser.getUid());
                    }
                    agentRepository.save(existingAgent);
                    if (pretendUser != null) {
                        return pretendUser;
                    }
                } else {
                    /* Check if pretendUID already present */
                    final String pretendUid = existingAgent.getPretendUid();
                    if (pretendUid != null) {
                        return userRepository.findByUid(pretendUid)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> {
                                    String msg = String.format("Pretend User not found for Uid: %s", pretendUid);
                                    logger.warn(msg);
                                    return new ResourceNotFoundException(msg);
                                });
                    }
                }

            }

            return existingAgent;
        }
        Optional<User> existingUser = userRepository.findByUid(token.sub);
        return existingUser.orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the user is part of the agent group
     * 
     * @param token
     * @return
     */
    protected boolean isAgent(TokenData token) {
        return token.groups != null && (token.groups.contains(AGENT.getCognitoName()) ||
                token.groups.contains(BRAND_OWNER.getCognitoName()) ||
                token.groups.contains(SUPER_ADMIN.getCognitoName()) ||
                token.groups.contains(VIEWER.getCognitoName()) ||
                token.groups.contains(AGENT_GROUP_NAME)); // TODO remove AGENT_GROUP_NAME with removing "agents" Cognito group
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the user is part of both the agent group and the internal group - for cross-agency access
     *
     * @param token
     * @return
     */
    protected boolean isInternal(TokenData token) {
        return this.isAgent(token) && token.groups.contains(INTERNAL_GROUP_NAME);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the logged in user and checks if he is authorized based class given. If the user is of different type it is also considered unauthorized
     * 
     * @param id
     * @param clazz
     * @return
     */
    protected <T extends IGenericUser> T checkAndGetUserAuthorized(Long id, Class<T> clazz) {
        T loggedInUser = checkAndGetUserAuthorized(clazz);
        if (!loggedInUser.getId().equals(id)) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
        return loggedInUser;
    }

    /**
     * Overload of {@link BaseController#checkAndGetUserAuthorized(Long, Class)} to accept uid instead of id
     * 
     * @param uid
     * @param clazz
     * @return
     */
    protected <T extends IGenericUser> T checkAndGetUserAuthorized(String uid, Class<T> clazz) {
        T loggedInUser = checkAndGetUserAuthorized(clazz);
        if (!loggedInUser.getUid().equals(uid)) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
        return loggedInUser;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the logged in user and checks if he is authorized based on the id and class given. If the user has a different id than the value provided throws
     * {@link UnauthorizedException}. If the user is of different type it is also considered unauthorized
     * 
     * @param clazz
     * @return
     */
    protected <T extends IGenericUser> T checkAndGetUserAuthorized(Class<T> clazz) {
        IGenericUser loggedInUser = getUserByToken();
        if (!clazz.isInstance(loggedInUser)) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }

        return (T) loggedInUser;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the logged in agent and checks if he has permission on the given campaignId. THe permission is checked based on the agency of the agent and the
     * given campaign
     */
    protected Agent checkAndGetAgentAuthorized(long campaignId) {
        IGenericUser loggedInUser = getUserByToken();
        if (!(loggedInUser instanceof Agent)) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }

        Agent agent = (Agent) loggedInUser;
        Campaign campaign = campaignRepository.findById(campaignId).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Campaign not found for id " + campaignId));
        if (!doesUserHaveRole(SUPER_ADMIN) && agent.getAgentBrandRoles().stream().noneMatch(role -> role.getAgencyBrand().equals(campaign.getAgencyBrand()))) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }

        return agent;
    }

    protected boolean doesUserHaveRole(RoleType roleType) {
        return request.isUserInRole(roleType.getSecurityName());
    }

    protected User verifyTMPermissionsAndGetSpecifiedInfluencer(User tm, TalentManagerPermission tmPermission, String infUidParam) {
        /* Check if an influencer Uid specified using infUidParam */
        String infUid = request.getParameter(infUidParam);
        if ((infUid == null) || (infUid.length() == 0)) {
            throw new BadRequestException(String.format("[%s] request param is needed when posting as the Talent Manager", infUidParam));
        }

        /* Check if specified influencer Uid is valid */
        User influencer = userRepository.findByUidAndType(infUid, UserType.INFLUENCER)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Influencer", "uid", infUid));

        /* check if this TM can post on behalf of specified influencer */
        Management management = managementRepository.findByInfluencerAndTalentManager(influencer, tm);
        if (management == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Influencer with uid %s not connected to current talent manager", infUid));
        } else if (!management.getManagementPermissionsSet().permits(tmPermission)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Insufficient privileges to carryout task on behalf of influencer %s", infUid));
        } else {
            return influencer;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you have this: public AgencyBrand() {} in a class called Entity. How did that even compile???

Comment: @Stultuske no, it is just old fragment. upd post

Comment: Show us the BaseController

Comment: @ThomasAndolf updated. It is just verify jwt, some auth methods..

Comment: Guys, any ideas?

Comment: And the EntityDTO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is based on a different Java version. When it was downgraded from 11 to 8 everything was fine.

Comment: The same issue happened to me on the 17 version of JDK. Downgrading to 11 fixed the issue.

Comment: Just had the same problem, downgrade from 17 to 11 helped as well.